# Assigning new variables during while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table that looks like this.

```
ID Type Quantity
-- ---- --------
1  car  25
2  motorcycle 10
3  bike 15
```

I am trying to figure out the best way create variables from this table.  I could run 3 different queries to get the data but I am sure there is a better way, but having trouble finding the answer with searches because I am not exactly sure how to verbalize what I want.

What I want is this-

```
$car = 25
$motorcycle = 10
$bike = 15
```

I could do

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT car FROM tablename");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$car = $row['Quantity'];
```

And then run the query 2 more times to get the other two variables I need but I know there is a better more efficient way probably inside of a loop.  Thank you

Comment: You're correct, there is definitely a better way.  Try it using a single query and share what you come up with. Then it'll be easier to steer you in the right direction instead of just writing the code for you.

Comment: What are you going to do next with the variables? Do you really need them as their own variable name? Is a php associative array acceptable?

Comment: The variables will be used several times for comparison, then based on the comparison will have quantities added to or subtracted from in php but not stored.

Comment: Dave I was thinking a single query with SELECT * then creating the variables in a while loop.  For example- while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){

Comment: Or maybe you are saying assign the variable right in the mysql query instead of in php?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the examples shown on php.net, which seem to be exactly what you're looking for:

Object-oriented style

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY ID DESC";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

Procedural style

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY ID DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Is this not the same as echo $row['Name']." ".$row['CountryCode'];  Not sure what to do with the data that is printed to the screen, need to capture to variables.  Maybe I am just not understanding.

Comment: @Tom you're correct, it is not a complete solution. It's a pointer in the right direction.  If you're unsure how to work with arrays, or how to utilize php variables, that's a specific question. This question, however, is borderline "Please write some code for me", so I'm trying to lead you toward either finding your own solution, or at least getting you to the point where you can ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $$row['type'] = $row['quantity']; 
}

echo $car."<br/>";
echo $motorcycle."<br/>";
echo $bike;
```

Comment: It didn't error, but it didn't return anything.

Comment: I just realized that your query is

`$result = mysqli_query("SELECT car FROM tablename");'

is that means "car" is your fieldname instead field value ?

Comment: Should have said type.